# Migrate a Windows Server 2012 from Aruba to Azure

Tags: azure

We have a windows server 2012 hosted by an Italian provider named Aruba.

The roles of the server are:

1. Active Directory
2. HMailServer
   3- SharePoint 2013
3. Project Server 2013
4. Team Foundation Server 2013

We have some doubt on how to migrate this server, of course the solution to crete a new VM in Azure and transfer users and roles is absolutely impossible as we will surely have bug problems during the migration of the role 3 4 5.

We have tried to create a VHD file using DSK2VHD, but after the upload of the disk to Azure, we wasn't able to create the Virtual machine.

What if we create a parallel machine in the Italian cloud and then use VmWare Converter to export the machine and subsequently convert it to Hyper-V and update to Azure ?

What is the best and reliable approach we should use to migrate correctly all?

Comment: You say that after uploading the VHD you weren't able to create the Virtual Machine - can you expand on that?

Comment: The VHD file isn't compatible with Azure

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your issue is due to size restriction or that the disk is not fixed size?

[Uploading the VHD using CSUpload](http://yossidahan.wordpress.com/2012/06/27/uploading-a-vhd-to-windows-azure/) could help as it will ensure the disk is converted to fixed size before uploading.

Comment: Seems that Azure want to use the VHD uploaded with CSUpload, only problem now is the size of the disk, the existing disk size is 200GB and Azure say that maximum have to be 128GB

Comment: You will need to shrink the VHD to fit the maximum size

Comment: I not a problem of the VHD file size, is a problem if the DISK size.